# Search in mongoDB array with php

Tags: php, mongodb

so my mongodb looks like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("60004358bd500000d3006cb3"),
        "Name" : "Tsakiris",
        "VAT" : "099360123",
        "DOY" : "----",
        "Address" : "some street",
        "TEL" : "2109750115",
        "Products" : [
                {
                        "pID" : "099360123/1",
                        "pNAME" : "Nike Air Force",
                        "pPRICE" : "95",
                        "pBRAND" : "Nike",
                        "pDESCRIPTION" : "50% green eco frindly",
                        "pCATEGORY" : "Trainers",
                        "pDEPARTMENT" : "Men/Shoes/Trainers",
                        "pTHUMBNAIL" : "http://127.0.0.1/pricedoc/assets/img/products/p1.jpg"
                },
                {
                        "pID" : "099360123/2",
                        "pNAME" : "Renato Garini boots",
                        "pPRICE" : "150",
                        "pBRAND" : "Renato Garini",
                        "pDESCRIPTION" : "autumn collection boot 2020",
                        "pCATEGORY" : "Βoot",
                        "pDEPARTMENT" : "Men/Shoes/Βoot",
                        "pTHUMBNAIL" : "http://127.0.0.1/pricedoc/assets/img/products/p2.jpg"
                }
        ],
        "nextProductCounter" : 3
}
```

I'm trying to select data with php

```
$options = ["typeMap" => ['root' => 'array', 'document' => 'array']];
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://127.0.0.1/", [], $options);
//$m= new MongoDB\Client ("mongodb://127.0.0.1/");
$db = $m->stores;
$collection = $db->storeinfo;   
$pID = $VAT."/1";
$products = $collection->findOne(array("Products.pID" => $pID));
//var_dump($products);
foreach ($products as $product) {
   echo $product;
}
```

But i have the Notice: Array to string conversion in
`D:\xampp\htdocs\pricedoc\assets\includes\library.php`

So i tried to convert it in json and search at json string
but still nothing.

I tried many things that found on the internet but it seems that i have stuck.
Is there a way to have the product's variables ?

example:

```
echo $product[Product.pID];     //output => 099360123/1

echo $product[Product.pName];   //output => Nike Air Force
```

Comment: Uncomment `var_dump($products);`.  What does that show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know MongoDB or what it returns, but you probably need to loop `Products`.  Given that JSON, they will be objects:

```
foreach ($products->Products as $product) {    
    echo $product->pID;     //output => 099360123/1        
    echo $product->pName;   //output => Nike Air Force    
}
```

Or if arrays are returned:

```
foreach ($products['Products'] as $product) {    
    echo $product['pID'];     //output => 099360123/1        
    echo $product['pName'];   //output => Nike Air Force    
}
```

Or some combination or the two. Your `var_dump($products);` will show you if you uncomment it.

Comment: Thank you very much!!